# Blob file upload - i am uploading image file from local system to azure blob container. Once uploaded, the file size shows as 0B with no extension

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have written a PHP code to upload files from the azure web app (using an upload button from a browser) to azure blob container. I am successfully able to upload the files to the blob container, however, once uploaded the file sits in azure blob as 0 bytes without any extension. I am unable to view the file as well and the following message is shown 'The file '1721405003' may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension'.

Below is my php code to upload files to blob -

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0); 
?>
<?php
  require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
  use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;
  use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;
  use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
  
  // If upload button is clicked ... 
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

  //upload to azure blob container
  $connectionString = "conn key"; //Enter deployment key
  $containerName = 'sidblobcontainer';
  $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);
  $file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
  $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $content = fopen($file_name, "r");
  $blob_name = "myblob".'.'.$ext;

  try {
    //Upload blob
    $blobClient->createBlockBlob($containerName, $blob_name, $content);
    echo "successfull";
    
  } catch (ServiceException $e) {
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message.PHP_EOL;
 }


    //upload to azure mysql database server
    $filename = $_FILES["myFile"]["name"]; 
    $tempname = $_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"];     
    $folder = "image/".$filename; 
        
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $db = mysqli_connect("demoserversid.mysql.database.azure.com", 
          "siddarth@demoserversid", "****", "images"); 
  
        // Get all the submitted data from the form 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (siddemo) VALUES ('$filename')"; 
  
        // Execute query 
        mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
          
        // Now let's move the uploaded image into the folder: image 
        if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder))  { 
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully"; 
        }else{ 
            $msg = "Failed to upload image"; 
      }
  } 
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM demo");
?> 
  
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<style> #content{ 
    width: 50%; 
    margin: 20px auto; 
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb; 
} 
form{ 
    width: 50%; 
    margin: 20px auto; 
} 
form div{ 
    margin-top: 5px; 
} 
#img_div{ 
    width: 80%; 
    padding: 5px; 
    margin: 15px auto; 
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb; 
} 
#img_div:after{ 
    content: ""; 
    display: block; 
    clear: both; 
} 
img{ 
    float: left; 
    margin: 5px; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 140px; 
}</style>
<title>Image Upload</title> 
<body>Upload to azure</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href ="style.css"/> 
<div id="content"> 
  
  <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <input type="file" name="uploadfile" value=""/> 
        
      <div> 
          <button type="submit" name="upload">UPLOAD</button> 
        </div> 
  </form> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

[Here is the message that I see in blob  container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukPCp.png)

Comment: I used the path info function of PHP.
 
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

But still, the file that I upload to azure shows without any extension. I am not sure if i have to configure something in azure blob storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the part that related to mysql and the code below works for me:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0); 
?>
<?php
  require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
  use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;
  use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;
  use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
  
  // If upload button is clicked ... 
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
      
 
  $connectionString = "<conn str>"; //Enter deployment key
  $containerName = '<container name>';
  $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);

  $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
  error_log($file_name);
  $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $content = fopen($_FILES['fileToUpload']["tmp_name"], "r");
  $blob_name = "myblob".'.'.$ext;

  try {
    //Upload blob
    $blobClient->createBlockBlob($containerName, $blob_name, $content);
    echo "successfull";
    
  } catch (ServiceException $e) {
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message.PHP_EOL;
 }
} 

?> 


<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<style> #content{ 
    width: 50%; 
    margin: 20px auto; 
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb; 
} 
form{ 
    width: 50%; 
    margin: 20px auto; 
} 
form div{ 
    margin-top: 5px; 
} 
#img_div{ 
    width: 80%; 
    padding: 5px; 
    margin: 15px auto; 
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb; 
} 
#img_div:after{ 
    content: ""; 
    display: block; 
    clear: both; 
} 
img{ 
    float: left; 
    margin: 5px; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 140px; 
}</style>
<title>Image Upload</title> 
<body>Upload to azure</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href ="style.css"/> 
<div id="content"> 

  <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/> 
        
      <div> 
          <button type="submit" name="upload">UPLOAD</button> 
        </div> 
  </form> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I used the path info function of PHP.
 
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

But still, the file that I upload to azure shows without any extension. I am not sure if i have to configure something in azure blob storage

Comment: @SiddarthBhaire, that's really weird, there is nothing needs to be config on Azure storage.Could you please share all of your codes(inclouds the file how to be uploaded) so that I can test it for you?

Comment: I have updated the post with the entire code (i am trying to upload image files to blob as well as mysql server. I have edited the post and put in the entire phtml code). Thanks for your help

Comment: @SiddarthBhaire Thanks for your code, I have updated my answer, please mark it if it is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am able to upload files onto azure blob now with your code :)